# how to use another table\query inside an update query

Tags: sql, sql-update, project, ms-access-2013

I tried to make an UPDATE query using data from another table
which in my case was a result of a query and it looks like this:

```
UPDATE CalculatedQueryINNER JOIN Orders 
ON CalculatedQuery.orderid = Orders.OrderID 
SET Orders.TotalPrice = [CalculatedQuery].[calculated];
```

But it's not working, it shows an error must use an updateable query

But i went and copied the results from the query to a table named temp and i did the same and it worked!!

```
UPDATE temp INNER JOIN Orders 
ON temp.orderid = Orders.OrderID 
SET Orders.TotalPrice = [temp].[calculated];
```

Can anyone please provide me with a solution on how to use the query as a table
please?

EDIT: I tried to treat a query as if it was a table by itself, that was my issue, joining tables is not an issue in update queries inaccess

Comment: What's the use of updating a (temporary) table? If you want to change a table, show us your database structure and which rows you want to change basing on which condition.

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot through different sites
The problem that I introduced is unsolvable in access.
There is an issue with the update queries since they are not standart in access.
The problem is That in access you can't use another sql query inside an update statement because as i read any queries that use group by or join or select within select etc.. Are marked as unupdateable queries and you can't use them.
As i read i found a few good solutions using a temporary table like i did
Or using dlookup() function.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you can also perform DELETE and UPDATE statements with a 'FROM', which will help in writing the query in a syntax that is more familiar. Given that you are running two very different update statements above, I've re-written both of them here. Also, given that you're using an Inner Join on both statements, which performs an intersect of data, I've rearranged the tables in the order of update.

```
UPDATE O
SET    [TotalPrice] = [T].[calculated]
FROM   [Orders] AS O
       INNER JOIN [temp] AS T
           ON [T].[orderid] = [O].[OrderID];

UPDATE O
SET    [TotalPrice] = [CQ].[calculated]
FROM   [Orders] as O
          INNER JOIN [CalculatedQuery] as CQ
              ON [CQ].[orderid] = [O].[OrderID];
```

Setting up your Updates (and likewise Deletes) in this syntax is pretty slick, as it allows for another nice feature: running a select to see what data will be changing:

```
SELECT [O].[TotalPrice]
    ,  [T].[calculated]
FROM   [Orders] AS O
       INNER JOIN [temp] AS T
           ON [T].[orderid] = [O].[OrderID];

SELECT [O].[TotalPrice], 
    ,  [CQ].[calculated]
FROM   [Orders] as O
          INNER JOIN [CalculatedQuery] as CQ
              ON [CQ].[orderid] = [O].[OrderID];
```